# Calculate average on 2 column value and apply condition to create new variable in R. (Help from Excel)

Tags: r, excel, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working on a dataset (which has more than 3000 rows), here is my simple explanation. I am looking to solve in R.

Please refer to the attached pic,

based on A, I want to create a new variable B.
Now, B1 "Low" is...  if A1 > AVG(A2, A3). So, here AVG of A2 and A3 is (2+5)/2 = 3.5, and hence the condition for A1 is lower than AVG of A2 and A3. So new variable answer B1 is "Low".

Now, we can easily solve this in Excel for 3000 rows (by creating a function and drag and drop button).
But, I need help to create a new variable B in R.

[image]

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a rolling mean calculation which would be helpful if you have to look for any number of entries in the future.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(B= ifelse(A > lead(rollapply(A, 2, mean, partial = TRUE, 
                            align = 'left')), 'High', 'Low'))

#      A B    
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     3 Low  
#2     2 Low  
#3     5 High 
#4     7 High 
#5     1 Low  
#6     3 NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

There is also `rollmean` function which performs rolling mean directly however, it lacks `partial = TRUE` argument which allows to perform partial calculation and return the value even when the entries are less than the window size.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution with the dplyr-package.

With the na.rm=TRUE/FALSE you can control if there is a NA in the second last row, because of the average of the leading two rows.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data_load <- tibble::tribble(
  ~A,
  3,
  2,
  5,
  7,
  1,
  3
)

data <- data_load %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lead1 = lead(A, n = 1)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lead2 = lead(A, n = 2)) %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(m = mean(c(lead1, lead2), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(B = dplyr::case_when(
    A >= m ~ "high",
    A < m ~ "low",
    TRUE ~ "NA"
  )) %>%
  dplyr::select(A, B)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>